# ssh: saving password in keyring app

Tags: terminal, password, keychain, ssh, two-factor-authentication

I am a user of a linux server with 2 level password authentication (public key+password). I log in with `ssh` on the terminal. My client is MacOSX. My passphrase for the public key is stored in the mac OS keyring app, but I cannot find a way to save my password.

Is there a way to save the password that I insert on the terminal?